# How to properly use Model Binding to get Radio Button value in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a set of radio buttons on a razor page, and I want to get and use the selected value of these radio buttons in my server-side code once the form has been submitted. HTML for radio buttons:

```
<label><input class="boost_radio" onclick="boostNo(1)" asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio" name="boostno" value=1 checked="checked" disabled="disabled" />1</label>
<label><input class="boost_radio" onclick="boostNo(2)" asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio" name="boostno" value=2 disabled="disabled" />2</label>
<label><input class="boost_radio" onclick="boostNo(3)" asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio" name="boostno" value=3 disabled="disabled" />3</label>
<label><input class="boost_radio" onclick="boostNo(4)" asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio" name="boostno" value=4 disabled="disabled" />4</label>
<span asp-validation-for="Boost_No.Number"></span>
```

I am using model binding to get the value on the server-side:

```
public class BoostNo
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select Number of Boost Units!")]
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

This class is instantiated as follows:

```
[BindProperty]
public BoostNo Boost_No { get; set; }
```

Unfortunately, every time I run the code, I get a `Boost_No.Number = 0`. I tried changing the data type to a string, but I just get `string = null`.

I am trying to use the model-bound variable in the handler method assigned to the form the radio buttons are contained in.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thanks.

**Edit:**

Here is the handler method in which the model binding is used:

```
public IActionResult OnPostSubmit()
{
    //save data to sql db
    SaveData();

    //then some other unrelated stuff
}
```

And the `SaveData()` method:

public void SaveData()

```
{
    //stuff

    //now how the radio button values are actually used
    for (int param_i = 1; param_i <= Boost_No.Number; param_i++)
    {
          //...
    }
    //then a paramaterized sql database query
}
```

Comment: Show you Controller Action code please

Comment: @AntonToshik There are no controllers in Razor Pages

Comment: @MikeBrind That was not a given, you understand what I mean though right? could you show the Razor Page OnPost() action or OnPostAsync() where are you posting this data?

Comment: @AntonToshik No - I didn't understand what you meant, which is why I made the comment. Lots of people see Razor Pages code and ask where the Controller is, assuming that the question is about a badly separated MVC application. FYI, the equivalent to a "controller action" in Razor Pages is a "handler method".

Comment: @MikeBrind I'm sorry I thought it was obvious what I was asking for. So I guess if you would like a more 'correct' question: Could you please show me the controller action or the razor page handler to which the form is posted?

Comment: @AntonToshik question updated

Comment: Can you show the form tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of your radio inputs are set to `disabled` so no value will be passed in the form collection when the form is submitted. Remove the `disabled` (and the `name`)  attributes from the inputs:

```
<label><input class="boost_radio" onclick="boostNo(1)" asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio" value=1 checked="checked" />1</label>
<label><input class="boost_radio" onclick="boostNo(2)" asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio"  value=2 />2</label>
<label><input class="boost_radio" onclick="boostNo(3)" asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio"  value=3 />3</label>
<label><input class="boost_radio" onclick="boostNo(4)" asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio"  value=4 />4</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a minimal Example I setup to make it work.

Here is my razor page handle and I use the same class implementation as you.

```
[BindProperty]
public BoostNo Boost_No { get; set; }

public IActionResult OnPost()
{
    return Page();
}
```

Now in the HTML

```
<label><input asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio value=1 checked="checked"/>1</label>
<label><input asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio" value=2/>2</label>
<label><input asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio" value=3/>3</label>
<label><input asp-for="Boost_No.Number" type="radio" value=4/>4</label>
```

Changes:

1. First remove the `name` attribute. Why? because the `asp-for` tag helper will create a `name` attribute for you. In addition to providing a `name` attribute you give it a value of `boostno`, the `name` attribute is used to bind the value to the Model, in other words your `OnPost` handle doesn't have a `boostno` parameter anywhere to get bound to.
2. Secondly if an input field is `disabled` the input value will be ignored. I would double check that before you submit the form open developer tools (F12) and double check your input field elements to make sure they are not disabled, even though the UI might suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

if these are individual radio buttons, you should have individual binding for each of those, for now you are using same for each of the radio button. (Boost_No.Number).
Either create a list of List and then bind individual radio button lik 
"Boost_No[0].Number" or create different properties for each of those (your choice)